# Are there any references to Eru or the Valar in the "Lord of the Rings" movies?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

The closest references to Eru or the Valar in Peter Jackson's *Lord of the Rings* and *The Hobbit* movies I can think of are Gandalf's vague description of his resurrection ("I've been sent back... until my task is done.") and his later description of Aman to Pippin ("White shores and beyond, a far green country under a swift sunrise." — as an aside, he's taunting Pippin here, since Hobbits suffer from the Gift of Men) and the equally vague information viewers are given about where the Elves are going when they leave Middle-earth.

Are there any more direct references I'm missing? Maybe a mention of Aulë by a dwarf?

Comment: Men do stop off at the halls of mandos, they don't leave right away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### *Fellowship of the Ring*

- There's at least one reference to Morgoth in the extended edition:

> **Celeborn:** Tell me, where is Gandalf, for I much to desire to speak with him. I can no longer see him from afar.
>
> **Galadriel:** Gandalf the Grey did not pass the borders of this land. He has fallen to shadow.
>
> **Legolas:** He was taken by a foe of shadow and flame: a balrog of Morgoth.
>
> <sup>*Fellowship of the Ring* (2003)</sup>

- Gandalf [alludes to both Eru and Morgoth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27801/what-does-gandalf-mean-by-secret-fire-flame-of-anor-and-flame-of-udun) in his fight with the balrog<sup>1</sup>:

> **Gandalf:** I am a servant of the Secret Fire, wielder of the flame of Anor. The dark fire will not avail you, flame of Udûn.
>
> <sup>*Fellowship of the Ring* (2003)</sup>

- There's at least one reference in the score; according to the *Fellowship of the Ring* annotated score, the full text of Arwen's prayer is:

> What Grace is given me, let it pass to him. Let him be spared. Mighty Valar, save him.
>
> <sup>*The Music of the Lord of the Rings Films Part 1: The Fellowship of the Ring The Annotated Score* Texts "Arwen's Prayer"</sup>

### *The Two Towers*

- When Aragorn is floating down the river, hallucinating Arwen, she says:

> **Arwen:** May the grace of the Valar protect you.
>
> <sup>*The Two Towers* (2004)</sup>

- In the next scene, between Arwen and Elrond, Valinor is called out by name:

> **Elrond:** Tollen i lû. I chair gwannar na Valannor. Si bado, no círar. (Arwen, it is time. The ships are leaving for Valinor. Go now... before it is too late.)
>
> <sup>*The Two Towers* (2004)</sup>

### *The Battle of the Five Armies*

- Galadriel has a throwaway line during her dust-up with Sauron<sup>3</sup>:

> **Sauron:** (in the Black Tongue) It has begun... The East will fall. So shall the Kingdom of Angmar rise. The time of the Elves is over. The Age of the Orc has come.
>
> **Galadriel:** You have no power here, servant of Morgoth.
>
> <sup>*The Battle of the Five Armies* (2014)</sup>

Considering Peter Jackson didn't have the rights to the *Silmarillion* material<sup>2</sup>, and very little mention of the Valar is made in the *Lord of the Rings* books themselves, I actually find it surprising that so many exist.

---

<sup>1</sup> Nod to [Hatandboots](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/45549/hatandboots) for reminding me of this one

<sup>2</sup> To the point where reference is made of the Blue Wizards in *An Unexpected Journey*, but Gandalf can't remember their names; the Blues are referenced in the Appendices, but their names are only revealed in *The Silmarillion* and *Unfinished Tales*

<sup>3</sup> Nod to [suchiuomizu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/30332/suchiuomizu) for pointing me to this one.

Comment: Maybe Gandalf's whole "I am a servant of the Secret Fire, wielder of the flame of Anor. You cannot pass. The dark fire will not avail you, flame of Udun. Go back to the shadow! You cannot pass."?

Comment: @Hatandboots Yep, forgot about that one; thanks

Comment: Are there any in the Hobbit movies? I've seen them, but I'm far less familiar with them.

Comment: @Plutor I'm not 100% confident at the moment, but I don't believe so; I'll get back to you

Comment: Galadriel called Sauron a 'servant of Morgoth' in the Battle of the Five Armies.

Comment: @suchiuomizu Yes, you are correct; thanks for the tip

Comment: Doesn't Frodo and/or Sam invoke Elbereth when fighting off Shelob?

Comment: @DougWarren Not in the movie; Frodo just invokes Eärendil

Comment: @DougWarren Frodo says "Aiya Eärendil Elenion Ancalima!" which means "Hail Eärendil, brightest of stars!". This was part of Eonwe's greeting to Earendil when he landed in the Undying Lands, to beseech the Valar for aid in the war against Morgoth in the First Age.

Comment: The Valar as a group are mentioned by name when the Ithilien rangers see the mûmak.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what's been said here, at the Battle of Helm's Deep, Aragorn addresses the assembled defenders in Elvish, crying "A Eruchin!" which means "O (ye) Sons of Eru!"

Comment: Good catch! Usually anglicised as eruhin I think https://www.elfdict.com/w/eruhin

Comment: @DavidRoberts Q: eruhini, S: eruchîn

Comment: @OrangeDog thanks for the correction!

Comment: @DavidRoberts it was from your own link

Comment: @OrangeDog I guess I didn't read down to the Sindarin entry. I do know the plural of eruhin is eruhini, but was getting the two languages confused, since I was assuming the OP was going for the singular, given the S. ending of -in.

Answer (score 4):

There's the scene of *The Passing of the Elves*, which is also a music piece by Howard Shore. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kzx2KQ7VM5E) is the movie snippet; apparently this was deleted from the theatrical release but happens to be on the extended DVD edition (which I am familiar with). The song, [*A Elbereth Gilthoniel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Elbereth_Gilthoniel), is a hymn to Varda. Shore's music composition is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Depf1gKhBno).

Curiously, as opposed to books, in the movies there's apparently *no* invocation of Elbereth either at Weathertop, or at the ford of Rivendell, or at Cirith Ungol (to name a few).

Comment: The name Elbereth was poisonous to Ungoliant and Shelob.  It is explicitly credited with pushing back darkness at critical times.